# Can't access my UI's widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have a MainWindow class which contains all widgets and I have a MyClass class where I want to access to all widgets placed in the main window (MainWindow class). How can I do this? I try to do it like this (code below) - but it gives me a bunch of errors:

```
MyClass.h:4: error: 'Ui' has not been declared
MyClass.h:4: error: expected `)' before '*' token
MyClass.h:6: error: 'Ui' has not been declared
MyClass.h:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'MainWindow' with no type
MyClass.h:6: error: expected ';' before '*' token
```

This MainWindow created by QtCreator - it's a standart GUI window created by Qt Creator.

```
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MyClass.h ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
#include "MainWindow.h"
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass( Ui::MainWindow *ui );
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MyClass.cpp ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass( Ui::MainWindow *ui ){
    this->myUI = ui; // myUI is desclared as: Ui::MainWindow *myUI
}

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MainWindow.h ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
....
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT    
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui; // this has done by Qt Creator
    public:
        MyClass *myClass;
}
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MainWindow.cpp ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
#include "MainWindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent ): QMainWindow( parent ), ui( new Ui::MainWindow ) {
    ui->setupUi( this );
    myClass = new MyClass( ui ); // my attempt
}
```

**Update:**
There's useful code in the comment below by beige. It works fine. But not in my case :( When I try to declare MyClass from any class (not from MainWindow.h):

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MyGLWidget.h ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
#include "MyClass.h"
class MyGLWidget : public QGLWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
     MyClass *myClass;
}
```

it doesn't work:

```
myclass.h:9: error: 'Ui' has not been declared
myclass.h:9: error: expected `)' before '*' token
myclass.h:12: error: 'Ui' has not been declared
myclass.h:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'MainWindow' with no type
myclass.h:12: error: expected ';' before '*' token
```

but why? I have declaration of the "ui_mainwindow.h" in my MyClass.h.

Comment: Is that the exact code you have? And do you get run-time errors or compiler errors?

Comment: on the line : "public: MyClass( Ui::MainWindow *ui );" of the MyClass.h, I give an error: "error: expected `)' before '*' token". Also compiler claims on this line: "private: Ui::MainWindow *ui;": "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'MainWindow' with no type".

Comment: Maybe someone can post some simple code with MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp which can access to the ui of the MainWindow?

Comment: You have to include "ui_..." first, or forward-declare the class Ui::MainWindow.

Comment: So MainWindow and Ui::MainWindow are two different things? Looks like you have to #include in MyClass.h the header that introduces Ui::MainWindow (or add a forward declaration).

Comment: @leemes, what is the "ui_..." files? :) It seems I don't have it :) What do you mean by "ui_..."?

Comment: @JavaRunner, the "ui_.." files are generated by the user interface compiler (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html). I've posted you some code that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MyClass header has to include the generated headerfile from the user interface compiler.   In your case, it is called ui_mainwindow.h. The constructor of MyClass will take the Ui::MainWindow parameter and save it in a private member variable.

In the constructor of MainWindow you can initialize your MyClass member variable with the MainWindow ui.

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ myclass.h ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(Ui::MainWindow *ui);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *myUi;
};
```

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ myclass.cpp ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
MyClass::MyClass(Ui::MainWindow *ui)
{
    // Save the MainWindow-ui as private member of MyClass
    this->myUi = ui;
}
```

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MainWindow.h ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "myclass.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyClass *myClass; // myClass member dont't has to be public
};
```

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[ MainWindow.cpp ]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Initialize MyClass with the MainWindow-ui
    myClass = new MyClass(ui);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete myClass;
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: That's wonderful code... you might want to add an explanation as well. ;)

Comment: yup, i want. I've added some comments. Also made the myClass member of MainWindow private and delete it in the destructor. I think, that will do :).

Comment: Better, but maybe add a sentence or two at the top on what solution your code actually demonstrates. This might also prevent it from showing up in our review tools for being code-only.

Comment: @Bart: Thanks for that info. May I ask you what the review tools are?

Comment: Thanks for the help! This code works! But when I try to declare MyClass from another class it doesn't work :( I've updated my first post

Comment: @beige They are categories of potentially problematic contributions (low quality, late answers, suggested edits, etc.) that are reviewed by members of the community. One of the "smells" for low quality is code-only answers. They are available under http://stackoverflow.com/review/ though a certain amount of rep might be needed to participate (don't exactly know the rules)

Comment: @Bart thank you verry much for the hint to write better answers. It says, that 125 rep is the lowest amount to gain accees to the first sections of that tool.

Comment: I can't use MyClass in other classes with this code, only in the class "MainWindow.h". Why it works like this?

Comment: @JavaRunner I can't see any mistake. Could you add the code from your MyClass.h? I've tried it exactly like your MyGlWidget and it works. Btw. I've updated my answer. My headerfile for MyClass is called myclass.h not MyClass.h.

Comment: My MyClass.h actually is your MyClass.h :) I use your MyClass.h - and it works fine when I declare MyClass from the MainWindow.h, but when I declare MyClass from another class (MyGLWidget.h) - it doesn't work (cause " 'Ui' has not been declared") - i don't know why it works like this :(

Comment: Have you used the include in your myclass.h with that braces like this: `#include <ui_mainwindow.h>` not with the quotation marks?

Comment: Yeah, I've copied MyClass.h from your sample. #include <ui_mainwindow.h> -- is in the braces!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17763/discussion-between-javarunner-and-beige)

Comment: could you post the contents of your actual myclass.h?

Comment: Yeah. I found that the root of my problem is promoting MyGLWidget to QWidget. This my little source with the error: http://www.file-upload.net/download-6677060/MyTestApp.zip.html
When I demote MyGLWidget from QWidget - it works again. But why??

Comment: Thanks to beige. He helped me a lot. The problem was in the promote-feature of the Qt Creator. If we set MyGLWidget manually (not promote via Qt Creator): `setCentralWidget(new MyGLWidget(this));` - it works well. Mysterious features :) But now it works :) @beige, thanks!